# What is the syntax to drop a Stored Procedure in SQL Server 2000?

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2000, sql-drop

Simple question, as the title suggests:

What is the syntax to drop a Stored Procedure (SP) in SQL Server 2000, by first checking that the SP exists?

Please provide the full code.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Microsoft recommended using the `object_id()` function, like so:

```
IF EXISTS (select * from dbo.sysobjects where id = object_id(N'[dbo].[YourProcedure]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsProcedure') = 1)
DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[YourProcedure]
GO
```

.
`object_id()` helps resolve owner conflicts.  If you do
`SELECT name FROM sysobjects WHERE name = 'my_procedure'`
, you may see many different procedures with the same name -- all for different owners.

But, `SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE id = object_id(N'[my_procedure]')` will only show you the one for the current owner/user, if more than one procedure by that name exists.

Still, always specify the object owner (default is `dbo`).   Not only does this avoid nasty side-effects, it's a little faster too.

Comment: I'm using MS SQL 2012, this syntax worked for me 

    DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[YourProcedure]

Answer (score 11):

Not for SQL Server 2000, but starting with SQL Server 2016, you can use the IF EXISTS syntax:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS [sp_ProcName]
```

Comment: This should be the top answer; OP got his solution a decade ago, this is now the correct one. Most people reading this don't need the clunky SQL Server 2000 solution.

Comment: That's not true, the question specifically asks for 2000, there are plenty of questions answering for newer versions.

Answer (score 10):

A slightly simpler method without going to system tables:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('my_procedure') IS NOT NULL DROP PROCEDURE my_procedure
GO
```

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sysobjects WHERE name = 'my_procedure' AND type = 'P')
DROP PROCEDURE my_procedure GO
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following if you want to remove multiple Procedures.
NB: This syntax works on SQL Server 2016 and later

```
USE [Database_name]
GO

BEGIN 
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS    'my_procedure1',
                            'my_procedure2',
                            'my_procedure3',
                            'my_procedure4',
                            'my_procedure5',
END
```

Answer (score -2):

In `SQL SERVER 2008`, if you want to drop a stored procedure just write the below command....

```
DROP PROC Procedure_name
DROP PROC dbo.spInsertUser
```

Hope it helps..